# Even and odd index in list

Tags: list, tcl

What is the best way in Tcl to split list A Into list B and list C
Where B will have even index items from A
and C will have odd index items from A.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. You may need to edit your question based on these guidelines. In particular, you need to show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using a [`foreach`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm) loop might be the easiest:

```
foreach {a b} $listC {
    lappend listA $a
    lappend listB $b
}
```

Comment: I am adding the values using argv. For example list a $argv.    Then values will be let say 3 4 6 2 1 8 and I want to pick 3 6 1 into list b and 4 2 8 into list c

Comment: @AayushiTomar Right... just replace `$listC` with `$argv`, and the other list with the variable names you need?

Comment: Let say I have file name as test.tcl.        So to execute I'll type tclsh test.tcl 3 4 6 2 1 8. Now I want to pick even index number and create a list b and odd index number to create list c

Comment: @AayushiTomar Ok, and what's the problem with that?

Comment: I don't know the code for it. ? How to store even position number to a list mentioned in the command line

Comment: @AayushiTomar What do you mean? The command line by itself cannot hold lists. If you want to print the two lists, you just need to use `puts`. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBktM.png